# Select distinct Cloudsearch AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

Now I'm doing this request on `CloudSearch`:

```
aws cloudsearchdomain --endpoint-url myUrl search --search-query France --query-options "{'fields':['country']}" --return name
```

I want to get only distinct names but i get names with id.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want vs what you're getting back? I'm a little unclear on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For this example array :

```
country | city | company_name | company_id | product_name | product_id 
US      | NY   | C1N          | C1id       | P1N          | P1id
US      | NY   | C1N          | C1id       | P2N          | P2id
US      | NY   | C2N          | C2id       | P1N          | P1id
```

I want to get all distinct company_name and company_id in NY

I do this request : `URL/search?q=NY&facet.company_id={sort:'count'}&q.options={"defaultOperator":"and","fields":["city"],"operators":["and","or"]}&return=_all_fields`

I get distinct company_id but i don't find a way to get company_name at the same time without making another request

```
    {
    "status": {
        "rid": "lKzEiL0qCwok24g=",
        "time-ms": 93
    },
    "hits": {
        "found": 2,
        "start": 0,
        "hit": [{
            "id": "369998744556855594878962245"
        }, {
            "id": "3699987477777545245"
        }]
    },
    "facets": {
        "company_id": {
            "buckets": [{
                "value": "C1id",
                "count": 2
            }, {
                "value": "C2id",
                "count": 1
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT : SOLUTION**

I found a solution : I store raw json data in a new column : 
`json_company = {\"id\":\"C1id\",\"name\":\"C1N\"}` and my request : `&facet.json_company ={}`

My result :

```
"facets": {
    "json_company": {
        "buckets": [{
            "value": "{\"id\":\"C1id\",\"name\":\"C1N\"}",
            "count": 2
        }, {
            "value": "{\"id\":\"C2id\",\"name\":\"C2N\"}",
            "count": 1
        }]
    }
```

I parse the JSON in my Lambda function !

Comment: You can specify as many facets as you want. Just add `&facet.company_name={}` and you'll get counts for that as well.

Comment: I see what you wanted now from your solution. Posting an example of the desired result can make the question a lot easier to understand. Thanks for following up with the solution you found. I have to say though, if there's a 1:1 relationship from `name` to `id` and you're returning them together to avoid having to look them up in your datastore, then you're not using CloudSearch for its intended purpose (that is, as a search engine rather than a datastore). Maybe that works ok for you but I would be cautious of doing that.