# AWS CloudSearch filter by unique values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

**My basic setup** :

I have an `AWS CloudSearch` domain where it stores objects for my code to make them searchable.  Each object is derived from a file somewhere and has a reference to the id of the file it's derived from.

**My question** :

Currently I send a search term and it returns the objects that match as expected.  However ***I would also like to have the option to only return one result from each file***. Is this possible?

I can certainly post process the results, but that would require getting all the results first which I don't want to do.  What I would is to tell `CloudSearch` on the server side to build the list of using unique results of the file id attribute, so basically if it finds a match it also checks if it already has any matches with that file id, if not it includes it but if so it excludes it.

Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Too add a little more detail, I have something conceptually like this:

[image: Object Layout]

So the actual objects are the definitions, but they come from files so they can have multiple definitions per file.  I need to be able to search definitions directly which I already am, but I would also like to be able to filter it by file so that it returns only one definition per file.  So in the above example if all 5 items matched the search it would return 1 and 4 (1 is the first definition in file 1, 4 is the first definition in file 2) even though 2,3, and 5 match the search as well.

Comment: If you want to return distinct value, look this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327457/select-distinct-cloudsearch-aws else if you want to return one "result" (= field?), use `&return=field_name, other_field_name`, doc here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/retrieving-data.html

Comment: That first one looks kind of like what I want but I'm not sure.  It looks like it's faceting on the company id in that example but only searching the city right?  I need it to search all fields, but filter to distinct files by ID...  Am I missing something?  I'm also using other faceting to get facets back to use in my UI.  Is the example showing using the facet data to get what I want?  Sorry trying to understand but still fairly new to CloudSearch...

Comment: I'm new too on Cloudsearch but I'm not sure about what you want : `only return one result from each file`, you have indexed the same file multiple time?

Comment: Added more detail to the question, hopefully that explains it better...

Comment: Ok, so you have one field for the "source field" and so you want to make the equivalent of a mysql `group by source_file`, that's it?

Comment: This one as a similar question, but no anwser...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526523/aws-cloud-search-grouping-search-results-by-field-value-and-returning-only-most

Comment: I don't find any solution, so if you find something I would be glad to learn how to do it ! Right now the only way I could do it is select all, transform the json response in php array and keep only "row" by source_file...but that's post process result as you said before